# What does `lsb` stands for in `lsb_release`?

Tags: versions, naming

I can get Ubuntu version by `lsb_release -a`.
To remember this command I want to know what stands for the `lsb`?

I found "Linux Standard Base" [here](http://www.abbreviations.com/LSB). Is this right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is true, See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base)

```
LSB=Linux Standard Base
```

Answer (score 13):

As most with most commands, the **manual** usually helps:

```
$ man lsb_release
```

> ...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The lsb_release command provides certain LSB (Linux Standard Base) and distribution-specific information.
>
> ...
>
> SEE ALSO
>
> ```
>     lsb(8)
> ```

Which leads to:

```
$ man lsb
```

> NAME
>
> ```
>   lsb - Linux Standard Base support for Debian
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  lsb package provides infrastructure for installing Linux Standard Base applications on Debian.  This manual page is designed to refer system adminstrators and others to the documentation available.
>
> The Linux Standard Base is a common runtime environment for third-party packages.  The goal of the LSB is to make it easy to create binary packages that will run on any Linux distribution.  For more information on the standard, please see the LSB web site.
>
> SEE ALSO
>
> ```
>   /usr/share/doc/lsb-core/README.Debian http://www.linuxbase.org/
> ```